# Constraints getting changed when adding a view over window or navigation controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, statusbar

I had an application in which I need to display a custom status bar over all the application. For which I wrote this code in to the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method

```
self.window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar;
```

Then in the viewController I created a view with (0, 0, width, 20) frame view and added some elements to it.

I am trying to add that view above the window like this

```
AppDelegate *appdelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[self.statusview setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
[appdelegate.window addSubview:statusview];
```

But it is getting added at the top left without having no elements. But when I am setting the width and adding the elements again then it is showing.

Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is the view's width, make sure the width is right.

if the width is right and the problem is still here, please update your code and screenshot.

Comment: i added the width constraint also,when i am adding this line  statusview.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 20);the elements inside it are not showing

Comment: change self.view.frame.size.width to [uiscreen mainscreen].bounds.size.width , try again.

Comment: same result.added correctly but the inside elements are missing

Comment: could you update more didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method codes.

Comment: i am doing this in a view controller with property view.nothing there.just a return yes

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
return YES;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
_statusview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, self.view.frame.size.width, 45);
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
_statusview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 45);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
_statusview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 45)];
_statusview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 25);
btn.center = _statusview.center;
[btn setTitle:@"button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[_statusview addSubview:btn];
[_statusview setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
[self.view addSubview:_statusview];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

put the code in the viewdidload. is that what you want ?

Comment: in fact, above the window or above the view, the effect is same.

Comment: If you need the view always above all views, All you need is a parent controller, and all the children controllers inherit the parent class.

Comment: if i set the frame then it won't show the inside elements.that i have already told u

Comment: could you tell me how you make elements in the view? i change my code and test, when i touchbegan or touchend the button always on the inside of statusview.